# How to Convert aspx website to mvc 4 or 5

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

I have been trying to convert some of our works websites to mvc web apps. I have been successful in converting them to web apps but the problem is implementing mvc. I have followed several tutorials but have failed. The most recent and promising was http://www.davepaquette.com/archive/2013/12/30/so-you-inherited-an-asp-net-web-forms-application.aspx#comment-3911.

I did most of it and the issue i have is the routes on the mvc area being recognized. I tried adding a new file Global.asax.cs to the project and include the app_start method but when I run the app the following error appears: 
[image: http://i.imgur.com/MikIYGz.png]

My Global.asax.cs looks as below

```html
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;

namespace TestWebApplicationMVC
{
    public class MvcApplication : System.Web.HttpApplication
    {
        protected void Application_Start()
        {
            AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
        }
    }
}
```

Any ideas or suggestions would be appreciated. I am fairly new to converting old websites to .net MVC hence the loss.

Comment: You might want to remove AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas(); in your global.asax file.

Comment: If I do that, My new routes are not found. I get a 404 error. Only my converted non mvc pages work.

Answer (score 1):

So I found out what the issue is. My old website already had a global.cs file with the Application_Start that was put on the Old_App_Code folder after conversion. What I did was add "AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();" to that global.cs file.

I suppose that eventually I can move that to the global.asax file.